# Where can I get a list of apps that are compatible/incompatible with Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, software, compatibility

Where can I get a list of apps so that I can check if my software is compatible or incompatible with Mountain Lion, so I know before I upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a comprehensive list on [roaringapps](http://roaringapps.com) that's kept up to date.